# Access to PhoneGap API

Tags: api, angularjs, cordova

Greetings Overflowers,

I am developing a phonegap app with AngularJS.
I am also building the app using the PhoneGap Cloud Build service.
I do not use any config.xml as I am relaying on the cloud service to include the default config.xml which has all the feature APIs included.
I am also including phonegap.js in my index.html as a script.
However, I am not able to access any of the PhoneGap APIs such as device and FileTransfer as they show up always as undefined.

Am I missing anything here?

Notes: I tried using custome config.xml but no help. I am testing on Samsung Galaxy S4.

Kind regards

Comment: I managed to get working by using PhoneGap 2.9. It seems that PhoneGap version 3+ treat API features as plugins and for some reason PhoneGap Build service do not add them by default. May be there is a new format for config.xml to do so. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

how are you loading the phonegap.js file?

I presume you know not to include the phonegap.js yourself as the build service adds the specific version needed into each platform that your building for.

Comment: I do not have a phonegap.js file in my app directory. I just include it in my index.html file for PhoneGap Build to substitute the right version for the platform with the same file name. Is there special way to load this phonegap.js file other than including it in the index.html?